# WGPU and Dawn (WebGpu)

Tags: webgpu, wgpu-rs

I am trying to understand the general concept of wgpu and Dawn.

As I understand it, there are two main implementations of the WebGPU standard from Khronos: wgpu from Mozilla and Dawn from Google.

Do I understand correctly that:

-wgpu: is it a C/Rust library that can be compiled from into an executable file of the Operating System and into WebAssembly code for the browser ?

-Dawn: Can only create Web Assembly code for the browser.

And I also wanted to ask: can wgpu create WebAssembly code, does wgpu convert only its API code or C/C++ code too? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, `wgpu` and `dawn` are the WebGPU spec implementations for `Firefox` and `Chrome` browsers respectively.

Currently, dawn is the most advanced implementation of the WebGPU spec, and will officially support WebGPU 1.0 in Chrome around May 2023.

A wgpu-based project compiled as a `wasm` target will be able to run on all WebGPU-enabled browsers.

More than that, the `wgpu` APIs is based on the WebGPU spec, but it can runs natively on Vulkan, Metal, Dx12, Dx11, and OpenGLES, and also provides additional features support for native applications.

For example, [wgpu-in-app](https://github.com/jinleili/wgpu-in-app) demonstrates how easy it is to integrate wgpu into iOS and/or Android app

Comment: Just wanted to also point out, that `dawn` can as well run natively see for example [`zgpu`](https://github.com/michal-z/zig-gamedev/tree/main/libs/zgpu) or [`machgpu`](https://machengine.org/gpu/) for `Zig` or [`hello-webgpu`](https://github.com/cwoffenden/hello-webgpu) for `C++`.

Comment: @frankenapps exactly what I wanted to make sure